# Why initialize lists with the new keyword rather than simply declare them?

Tags: c#, list, generics, new-operator

I have a basic grasp on the C# language, knowing *how* to do things without much understanding of *why*. I noticed today that I habitually add the `new` keyword when initializing a list (ex. `public List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();`) without realizing why I am doing the initialization in the first place. This just piqued my curiosity and I had to come here and ask (*after searching of course*).

I tried simply declaring the list

```
public List<Foo> foos;
```

and it worked just fine with my code, so why was I taught to always initialize lists with the `new` keyword?
What is the difference?
I assume it has to do with allocating memory, but again, I have an elementary understanding of such things.

---

**SOLVED:** @JOSEFtw's answer below demonstrated that Unity's compiler will automatically initialize a list that is simply declared with `public List<Foo> foos;`. This got me mixed up and anywhere outside of Unity will throw a NullReferenceException if you don't initialize a list.

---

**EDIT:** @UnholySheep asked for a minimal, reproducible example in the comments. After struggling with formatting there, I decided to add it here:

```
public class ListManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<int> ints;

    public void AddInt(int i)
    {
        ints.Add(i);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        AddInt(3);
        AddInt(6);
        AddInt(9);

        foreach (int i in ints)
            Debug.Log($"Int {ints.IndexOf(i) + 1} is {i}");
    }
}
```

For me, this produces the result:

```
Int 1 is 3
Int 2 is 6
Int 3 is 9
```

even though a NullReferenceException is to be expected.

This is using Unity's compiler, which could be why `public List<int> ints;` is working the same as `public List<int> ints = new List<int>();`. Perhaps it's just the compiler making things proper in the background? For those unfamiliar with Unity, `Debug.Log` is similar to `Console.WriteLine` and `void Start()` is similar to `void main()`.

Comment: It's hard to know what code worked without seeing the rest of it. If you just declare the variable, it will have an initial value of `null`. That's not a problem if something *else* initializes it to a non-null reference, but if you just tries `foos.Add(new Foo());` without initializing it *somewhere*, you'd get a NullReferenceException. There's nothing special about lists here - the default value for a reference type field is always null.

Comment: Why? Because. Lists are objects and creating them means to call one of their possibly several constructors. You can't do anything with an uninitalized object other than assigning another object to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I populated the list elsewhere and that's more why I was wondering why even use the `new` keyword. In code examples that I have seen, from people using lists in roughly the same way by populating it elsewhere in the code, they still used `new List<Foo>()` to initialize the field. Is that just good practice or is there any harm in simply declaring the variable? I can provide code examples, but basically, I declared a list of items with `public List<Item> items;` then populated the list using the function `void AddItem(Item i) { items.Add(i); }`

Comment: If you never assign a `new List<Item>` to `items`, then `items.Add(i);` will throw an exception at runtime

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it didn't. I thought it would throw a NullReferenceException when I tried it, but it ran with no errors/warnings. That made me wonder if `new List<Items>` was redundant or perhaps the compiler is automatically doing that behind the scenes for me?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing this behavior

Comment: I updated my question with an example.

Comment: Please call out the exact type of the `List` you're using; the example without it throws the expected NRE.

Comment: I have to use `System.Collections.Generic` to utilize it. I'm guessing it still allows it because of Unity magic at this point. In any case, I'll continue initializing my lists properly; Unity just tripped me up. I didn't think to test it with a different compiler.

Comment: Maybe `MonoBehaviour` in its constructor initializes all `public` members of the object via reflection. Try setting it to `private`.

Comment: As I said, I only have a basic grasp of C#, so I'm sorry for not knowing how to do this. Would I have to use the `override` keyword somewhere for `MonoBehaviour`? That's where all of Unity's 'magic' happens, so I would hate to screw something up.

Edit: I can't find MonoBehaviour when looking at the assemblies in Visual Studio references. That's why I'm wondering if the `override` keyword could be used somewhere (although, I've never used it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I now see that you are using Unity. 
Take a look at this answer: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129346

> Unity's editor automatically creates the new List () part when generating the game

The below portion of my answer still stands true though if you are not using Unity.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static List<string> MyList;
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyList.Add("boom");
    }
}
```

Will throw the following error if you try to use it without initialize it:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I created a fiddle for you that shows what happens if you run the code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dUlxo6

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I expected as well, but it didn't happen in my program. Do you know if Unity's compiler does magic in the background and automatically initializes an uninitialized list with a new list object? I updated my question with an example.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't think to test in a separate compiler so thank you for that; Unity really did trip me up here. I will continue to initialize lists properly regardless. Thank you and everyone else who answered!